# What are all those compilers?

Tags: c++, qt, clang, qt-creator, apple-m1

Got an M1 MacBook and installed Qt using the online installer. Head to QtCreator Preferences and saw:

[image]

[image]

What are all those compilers?

And, if I may ask, am I using the right one?

Comment: *"which should I use?..."* Seems Opinion-based

Comment: You should use the one for your platform and the language you intend to use. I see no reason to not trust what Qt detected.

Comment: @JasonLiam Not really

Comment: @PaulSanders Every single option given in the shown list can be used by someone. For example, there are say 7 different options given in the list above. Now there can be 7 different answers saying that "they would use option `i`" where i is the index of the option. Without knowing for what use case and what requirements OP is asking the question, all of those 7 answer would be correct and those answers wouldn't even have to specify any reason for why they're using that option because the question is "am i using the right one"? How can we tell what is right for them ?

Comment: @JasonLiam In that case, ask the OP what his use-case is.

Comment: Would it be appropriate to ask for an answer elaborating the use cases of each of them? I would guess one is native (arm64) and others are there for cross compilation purposes, right?

Comment: @KcFnMi Sounds reasonable, I'll give it a go shortly.

Comment: OK OP, the (best) answer depends on what platforms you want to support.  If it's just your own M1 Mac then that uses the arm64 architecture and I would go for Apple Clang (see my comment to @quimby's answer below).  The resulting binary will also run on an M2 Mac.  If you want to support additional platforms than this, please tell us which.  What I *don't* know is whether the Qt libraries are (or need to be) built for your target platform(s) and how to get the best out of QtCreator.  Maybe someone else here knows that.

Comment: Point is, the Mac supports 'fat binaries' containing more than one architecture and I don't know if QtCreator can build one of those.  It's a really nice feature for those of us who want to support both Intel and M1/M2 Macs with a single distribution.

Comment: I did a quick test, build a C++ hello world on M1 then copied and tried to run in on an intel Mac. Got a "bad CPU type in executable" message.

Comment: OK, it's not a fat binary then. You'll have to do some digging, I don't know how to solve that one in the context of QtCreator and CMake, but basically you have to compile and link everything twice (once for each architecture) and then use `lipo` to stitch the two individual binaries together to produce a fat binary which will run on both types of processor. (I use Xcode, which automates all that.) Also, you will need, somehow, Qt libraries for both architectures. Are you using dynamic Qt libraries (.dylib) or are you linking statically (.a)? It may be that the ones out of the box are 'fat'.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from C/C++ distinction, the compilers are for different target processor architectures (clang is a cross-compiler).

It also looks like QT installed a bunch of them and there are also local ones at `/usr/bin` that were installed by some other software.

Apple M1 is ARM-based so you need `arm64` one. Or possibly use those local ones at `/usr/bin/` as they might be set to native compilation by default.

You might as well try to compile Hello World with different ones and see which binaries can be launched.

Comment: You can also use the `file` command at the command line to see the architecture(s) present in a binary (there can be more than one on the Mac)

Comment: There's a lot to be said for using Apple clang - it plays nice with the runtime libraries generally installed on the Mac (and on other peoples' Macs...)

Comment: @PaulSanders To be honest I do not have much experience, zero with M1, just wanted to give OP an overview, hopefully some will work just fine.

Comment: OK.  I'm in the opposite corner - I develop actively for the Mac but have never used QT.

Comment: In my experience, often times many relatively equivalent compilers show up on that list, but some of them play nicely with QtCreator's IDE features (e.g. the red squiggles) and others don't.

Comment: @PaulSanders Qt is not an issue here, it's cross-platform (mac OS is supported otherwise OP would not be able to install the IDE QtCreator for mac (it would not make sense to provide a release for their IDE on mac OS if it is not supported by Qt)). After the Qt C++ code is processed by the qt meta-object compiler, the generated moc files are "pure" C++ code that can be compiled by any available compiler.